# Target table schema change and update policy

Tags: azure-data-explorer

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy) says:

> The update policy function schema and the target table schema must match in their column names, types, and order.

What is the behavior when the target table schema needs to be updated? Will it fail or will that cause the update policy to fail?

If none fails, will the source table data stop being processed into the target table?

Answer (score 1):

if there is a mismatch between the schema of the target table and the output schema of the query in the update policy - the update policy will fail.

And, if the update policy is configured with `IsTransactional` set to `true` - the entire ingestion will fail.

- In managed ingestion flows, e.g. ingestion from event hub, or any other kind of queued ingestion - the service will automatically retry the ingestion operation in this failure scenario.

  - This means that there's a 'grace period' during which you can perform the desired schema changes, after which these retries will succeed (assuming you've resolved all schema mismatches)

This, too, is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy#treatment-of-failures) (partial snippet included below)

[image]